# Formula to find number of JOINS for 100 tables or more

Tags: sql, database, join, rdbms

Can anyone help me in formulating an expression to find total number of JOINS will be if we have 100 or more tables.

Comment: Joining **n** tables requires **n-1** joins.

Comment: Even with only two fields each, the number of combinations would be more than the number of atoms in the known universe

Answer (score 0):

There's no limit to the number of times you can join, besides processing and memory restrictions and limits in the implementation of the query evaluator.  Even a single table can be joined to itself any number of times.